# Illustrator - make text wrap instead of scale

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a chunk of text I need to paste into Illustrator. No matter what I do, I can't resize the text area without scaling the text. I want to resize the area and have the text wrap (font size to remain the same).

How can I do this? I'm using CS5.1

Comment: See this response also:
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4791/3145

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select your `Type` tool.  Instead of clicking on your canvas, click and drag to draw a box.  Put whatever copy you want inside the type box and when you resize the box it will reflow the text instead of changing the font.

You can also link multiple type boxes together to flow text across multiple points on your artboard.  Create type objects wherever you want text to be.  Add all your copy to the first box.  Assuming it overflows, there will be a [image: +] symbol in the bottom-right corner of the type box.  Click this [image: +] symbol and then click the next type box where you want text to flow.  Illustrator will flow text through as many type boxes as you link together.

Answer (score 18):

OK, here goes.

If you have already type some text using the type tool and selected this text using `Selection Tool`(the black arrow), you will see something like this

[image]

have you notice the rightmost circle?

[image]

just move the cursor on to this circle, double click it, and you'll see this

[image]

OK, now you can adjust the border of this text box without shrinking the characters, but it takes two steps, first

[image]

to notice there is a [image] which means there are some text hidden. Then, second step increase the height of the box, the word "here" automatically wrapped to the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great article, **["Make Illustrator behave!"](http://www.creativepro.com/article/make-illustrator-behave-)** that explains it all in in full.

Figuring out under what circumstances Illustrator scales the many types of text object and when it scales the bounding box, wrapping the text, is a common frustration.

The differences between the different types of text object in Illustrator are brilliant once you've mastered and made sense of them, but massively frustrating until you do so...

I really recommend taking some time out to go through that article in full.