# Merge Point Text Objects Into One Text Area In Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, pdf, automation, illustrator-scripting

After importing from PDF I have several single line point text objects which I want to convert to one multiline text area object.

Currently I have several lines of text represented as separate point text objects:
[image]

I want to have one text area for the whole paragraph:
[image]

Also I would like to automate this somehow, since I have about 40 of these paragraph of texts in my graphic, so I don't need select and  merge all of them manually:
[image]

PS: I'm aware about copy and paste solution (selecting multiple text objects), but it doesn't work for me, because it's a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajar Productions has a script called [Merge Text](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2008/11/23/merge-text-extension-for-illustrator/) that does mostly what you want, except it turns the text into a big point text. You may need to adjust spacing after this tough as the script toolset is a bit simplistic.

Illustrator Praxis has a set of [text tools](http://illustrator.hilfdirselbst.ch/dokuwiki/en/skripte/javascript/tx_tools) that can do this with a little more work. For one they have a script to turn point texts into textboxes. This script set is a bit more complex but allows for so many more situations such as lines broken by kerning etc.

As a alternate option, *Hiroyuki Sato* has implemented a nice workaround for situations like this. He has a script called [batchTextEdit.jsx](https://github.com/shspage/illustrator-scripts#batchtexteditjsx) that will allow you to conveniently edit the texts as if they were in same textbox.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything, which can detect blocks of text automatically, so I don't need to select text objects each time? For example it could detect is there any text object in radius of 10 pixel and if yes, merge them together.

Comment: @MarkVital not that i know of, i made a rudimentary prototype yesterday for this kind of automatic building but its really early days.

Answer (score 2):

This [other similar QA has an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/24595/19447) that really helped me:

> If you'd like to merge broken text while preserving as much of the
>   formatting, placement, paragraphs and other typography of the existing
>   text as you can, rather than pasting into a newly created text area as
>   plain text, you can try [John Wundes' amazing **Join Text Frames**
>   script](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/).
>
> It does exactly what it says on the tin: it merges snippets of text
>   into one snippet of text, by making intelligent judgements based on
>   where they are relative to each other:
>
> - It merges adjascent text snippets (e.g. from broken lines of text from PDFs) into single lines, with some control offered over how close
>     is considered to be the same line.
> - It merges separate lines of text into one multi-line text object with the text in the right order (top to bottom), fixing broken
>     paragraphs.
> - There's then an option to restore the original formatting of all the merged text. This can take a while, but it helpfully gives you
>     pretty accurate estimates of how long it will take and the option to
>     skip if it's not worth it.

Comment: No suggestions? Just adding negativity into GD? Sorry for trying to share what helped me.

Comment: Upvote. This is one I've been using for years, it's legit, and it's been around for ages.